# ISPManager, одна директория со всех поддоменов

Tags: dns, ispmanager

Нужно в ISPManager направить все поддомены на директорию основного. Т.е. что бы, если пользователь открывает 1.site.ru ему открылось всё то же, что и на site.ru

В настройках нашёл только реализацию для поддоменов, как отдельных сайтов, с их расположением либо в отдельной директории, либо внутри site.ru

Куда можно с этим копнуть, в какую сторону смотреть? Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках `virtualhosts` указал как `ServerAlias` *.domain.name.

И всё заработало.